# Arreglo de EditText en Android

Tags: android

Quisiera saber si lo estoy haciendo correctamente.
Tengo muchos EditText y es dificil estar haciendo casting por casting asignando.

Ante esto hago lo siguiente:

```
EditText[] Informacion;
Informacion = new EditText[]{
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_huerto),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_ubicacion),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_propietario),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_fijo),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_celular),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_productor),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_mercado),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_ponderado),
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_descripcion)};
```

pero me los marca null al momento de  hacer:

```
Informacion[0].setText("091783172831");
```

> `Error!`
>   `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 2):

Eso es porque no has creado bien el objeto de tu EditText, una forma sería la siguiente

```
EditText[] Informacion;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .........
    Informacion = new EditText[]{createEditView(R.id.informacion_huerto),
            createEditView(R.id.informacion_propietario),
            createEditView(R.id.informacion_ubicacion)};
    Informacion[0].setText("091783172831");
}

public EditText createEditView(int id){
    EditText texto = (EditText) findViewById(id);
    return texto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText[] Informacion;
```

Asegúrate de obtener als vistas con findViewById() después de añadir el layout que contiene estas vistas

```
//primero esto
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

//después ya puedes obtener los EditText
    Informacion = new EditText[]{
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_huerto),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_ubicacion),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_propietario),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_fijo),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_celular),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_productor),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_mercado),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_ponderado),
                    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.informacion_descripcion)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que podrías hacerlo de dos maneras:

**A. Almacenando los EditText en un array:**

```
EditText[] Informacion  = {informacion_huerto, informacion_ubicacion,
                           informacion_propietario, informacion_fijo,
                           informacion_celular, informacion_productor,           
                           informacion_mercado, informacion_ponderado,
                           informacion_descripcion};
```

**B. Almacenando los EditText en un arrayList:**

```
   List<EditText> Informacion = new ArrayList<EditText>(){{
     add(informacion_huerto);
     add(informacion_ubicacion);
     add(informacion_propietario);
     add(informacion_fijo);
     add(informacion_celular);
     add(informacion_productor);
     add(informacion_mercado);
     add(informacion_ponderado);
     add(informacion_descripcion);
   }};
```

No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar de las dos formas.

De este ejemplo podrías sacar también, quizás, algo interesante: [Add EditText(s) dynamically and retrieve values - Android](http://prasans.info/2011/03/add-edittexts-dynamically-and-retrieve-values-android/)